# QGIS, scale not correct after export

Tags: qgis

I am trying to create a hiking map. I use print composer to print a section of the map and let print composer create a UTM grid with 1000 map units distance. after i print to pdf and then to paper (A4), I measure using a ruler that the the distance between 5 grid lines is not 200mm as expected but 201mm. the features on the map is also stretched by 1 mm.

when i change the grid option in print composer to use mm instead, the grid is 200mm as expected so this is not a printer setting.

How can I fix this "stretching"?

Version: QGIS 2.18 windows and  2.18 ubuntugis
project CSR: WSG_84 / UTM32N
Map location: UTM zone 32V
scale in canvas and print composer: 1:25000

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the settings in the print dialogue box when you click to print the PDF using your printer. There may be a scaling option, or manual scaling setting on there that you've missed.

Comment: I have triple checked this =) the mm based grid generated by print composer is not scaled, so this must be something in qgis or how i use it. or maybe i have too high expectations of the accuracy, i am new to GIS software.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I do not know exactly what the issue was but now it seems to be solved.

I tried some things some things without luck:
-use foxxit pdf printer, set its a4 size to mm.
-check "avoid artifacts when renderes as tiles".

but it did not work before i created a new project and set everything up this way again.